# Yii2 advanced - enable pretty URL in module

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-routing, yii-rest

I am learning how modules work in Yii2 and now I created the following module: `gdpr`. I can access the following route: `/index.php?r=gdpr/user/index`. However, I want to access the route like this: `/gdpr/user/index`. How can I achieve that?

config.php:

```
<?php
return [
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'modules\gdpr\default'],
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'modules\gdpr\user'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => [
        // list of parameters
    ],
];
```

Comment: were you able to solve the problem using the answer below? or still looking for help

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure controllers in this way:

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'controller' => ['gdpr/default', 'gdpr/user'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

See https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-urlrule#$controller-detail